# Dynamic border of a rectangle

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, nested-loops

I want to create a hallow rectangle with a dynamic border, which means that if I input 3, then the border is going to be 3 columns thick. I've managed to do it with pre-given value, but I want the values to be inputted by the user.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, n, m;
    printf("Rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Columns: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
        for(j=1; j<=m; j++){
            if(i==1 || i==2 || i==3 || i==n-2 || i==n-1 || i==n || j==1 || j==2 || j== 3 || j==m-2 || j==m-1 || j==m){
                printf("*");
            }
            else{
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about putting the inserted value in a for loop and then iterating and saving the values. Then in the nested for loop, inside the if statement i would substract n-(loop iteration value), but i can't seem to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you wanted to print a single row of 1000 spaces:

```
for(j=1; j<=1000; ++j){
  printf(" ");
}
```

So far, so good. Now suppose you want the first three characters to be asterisks:

```
for(j=1; j<=1000; ++j){
  if(j==1 || j==2 || j== 3){
    printf("*");
  }
  else{
    printf(" ");
  }
}
```

That works. There are other ways, but that works.

Now suppose you want the first 200 characters to be asterisks:

```
for(j=1; j<=1000; ++j){
  if(j==1 || j==2 || j== 3 || j==4 || ...
```

All right, this is clearly not the right approach. Good programmers dislike typing. Let's try one of the other ways:

```
for(j=1; j<=1000; ++j){
  if(j<=200)
    printf("*");
   else
    printf(" ");
```

That works. Here's another way, even better:

```
for(j=1; j<=200; ++j)
  printf("*");
for(j=201; j<=1000; ++j)
  printf(" ");
```

Now suppose you want the first 200 and last 200 characters to be asterisks:

```
for(j=1; j<=200; ++j)
  printf("*");
for(j=201; j<=1000-200; ++j)
  printf(" ");
for(j=1000-200+1; j<=1000; ++j)
  printf("*");
```

That should be enough to show you how to rewrite your code for rectangular borders.